# Django Model design

Tags: python, django, django-models

I needed some help in model design. I wanted a model where a user can associate himself with numerous emails by submitting them from a form. And when the user wants to use the websites contact form, he can choose the email he wants a reply on. Will it be something like this :

```
class Email(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Contact(models.Model)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    email = models.ForeignKey(Email)
```

Comment: There is no 'ForeignField' in Django - it's `ForeignKey`.

Comment: The Contact model doesn't need the author field. The author is accessible from the email field of the Contact model. Other than that, this seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example means each Contact can have a single email address, and each email address can belong to multiple contacts. This is the wrong way round, i.e. you should put the ForeignKey on the Email model.

This should let you store multiple email addresses for each user.

```
class Email(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

u = User.objects.get(pk=1)
u.email_set.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a user profile to your users.

```
from django.contrib import auth

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """A user profile."""
    user = models.OneToOneField(auth.models.User)
    # ... put more fields here


def user_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """Make sure that every new user gets a profile."""
    profile, new = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

models.signals.post_save.connect(user_post_save, sender=auth.models.User)
```

then you can access it with `request.user.get_profile()`.

Comment: Well, with this you are taking advantage of things Django has built-in for this purpose. You are probably going to add more things to your user's profile anyways.